# Running SSIS package in C# .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to run an SSIS package from a simple console app. Unfortunately I am stuck on some errors`

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Threading.Tasks;
       using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices;
       using System.Data.SqlClient;

         namespace SSIStutorial
     {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Variables
        string targetServerName = "localhost";
        string folderName = "Projects";
        string projectName = "SSIS Tutorial";
        string packageName = "Lesson 1.dtsx";

        // Create a connection to the server
        string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source = cgol1793109; Initial Catalog = TEST; Integrated Security=True;";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

        // Create the Integration Services object
        IntegrationServices integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(sqlConnection);

        // Get the Integration Services catalog
        Catalog catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"];

        // Get the folder
        CatalogFolder folder = catalog.Folders[folderName];

        // Get the project
        ProjectInfo project = folder.Projects[projectName];

        // Get the package
        PackageInfo package = project.Packages[packageName];

        // Run the package
        package.Execute(false, null);
    }
}
}
```

I get the following while instantiating the IntegrationServices object of the type IntegrationServices.
I get the following error.

> System.MissingMethodException
> HResult=0x80131513
> Message=Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlStoreConnection..ctor(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)'.
> Source=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices..ctor(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
> at SSIStutorial.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\kokoro\source\repos\SSIStutorial\Program.cs:line 26

Comment: I don't see a constrructor overload that takes a connection string in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.integrationservices?view=sqlserver-2019)

Comment: I passed in a sqlConnection object and not a string

Comment: Looks approximately correct. Is there an `SSISDB` database on `cgol1793109`? The other observation is that I usually see no spacing around the equals sign or the semicolon in the connection string, thus `"Data Source=cgol1793109;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True;"`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with my console app. Followed all the steps on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-dotnet?view=sql-server-ver15) and it didn't work, got exactly the same error as you *Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlStoreConnection..ctor(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)'*.

The Microsoft docs solution doesn't work on a Console App (.NET Core), it only works on a Console App (.NET Framework).

I guess you are trying to run in on a Console App (.NET Core)? I changed mine to .NET Framework and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-dotnet?view=sql-server-ver15), the steps you used to define a connection and to instantiate the IntegrationServices object are correct. This means that the issue is caused by the connection string. Try to remove the additional spaces, edit the Integrated security parameter, and use the master database as the Initial catalog:

```cs
string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=cgol1793109;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
```